# How can json datas can be prevented from reload Cypress servers?

Tags: json, module, filesystems, cypress, reload

I am reading json datas by using const testData = require('../test.json') module in cypress.
Now when I am using a cy.writeFile(../test.json,obj) tag and updating the json in a test case then my whole server is getting refreshed..
How can I prevent the server to reload...